# Display two posts from each post type with wp_query

Tags: wordpress, post

I have used the following code to display the one post from each post.

```
  $post_types = array('a', 's','d','f','g');//post type names
  foreach( $post_types as $post_type) :
  // The Query
  $the_query = new WP_Query( array(  'post_type' => $post_type,
                                     'orderby' => 'post_date',
                                     'order' => 'DESC',
                                     ));
  // The Loop
  ?>
  <?php
  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
  <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
    <div class="issue-content masonItem <?php echo $post_type; ?>">
      <?php
        $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
        $resizedUrl = get_bloginfo('template_url')."/libs/timthumb.php?src=".$url."&amp;w=327&amp;h=204&amp;zc=1"; ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $post_type == 'news' ? site_url('/news')  : the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $resizedUrl; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="masonry-thumb" /></a>

      <?php get_template_part( 'content-issues', 'page' );?>
    </div><!--issue-content--><!--Mason Item-->
    <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endwhile;
```

Now i want to display 2 posts from each post type. How can i do this ? I got the $post_count idea. But i cant know use it in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
'posts_per_page' => 2,
```

Answer (score 0):

You try This

```
  $the_query = new WP_Query( array(  'post_type' => $post_type,'orderby' => 'post_date','posts_per_page' => 2,'order' => 'DESC'));
```